# MISRA-C warning during initialization enum type

Tags: c, enums, misra

Following enum defined in my code

```
typedef enum e_gpio_pin
{
    GPIO_PIN_1 = 1,     /*!< pin 1 */
    GPIO_PIN_2,         /*!< pin 2 */
    GPIO_PIN_3,         /*!< pin 3 */
    GPIO_PIN_4,         /*!< pin 4 */
    GPIO_PIN_5,         /*!< pin 5 */
    GPIO_PIN_6,         /*!< pin 6 */
    GPIO_PIN_7,         /*!< pin 7 */
    GPIO_PIN_8,         /*!< pin 8 */
    GPIO_PIN_9,         /*!< pin 9 */
    GPIO_PIN_10,            /*!< pin 10 */
    GPIO_PIN_FIRST = GPIO_PIN_1,    /*!< first pin */
    GPIO_PIN_LAST = GPIO_PIN_10 /*!< last pin */
} T_GPIO_PIN;
```

Now below line have used to initialize the variable.

```
 static const T_GPIO_PIN ioPin = GPIO_PIN_9;
```

and i got below warning

> An expression value of essential type 'Essentially
>   Enum' is assigned to an object of essential type
>   'Essentially Enum' comment : MISRA 10.3 (C90-2012 req.)

is anyone have idea how can i resolve this warning?

Comment: Misra 10.3 rule is saying Casting to a narrower type but your initialization is fine.

Comment: which tool you are using? LDRA ?

Comment: Yeah please post the tool name so they get named and shamed in public. There's so many crappy analysers out there.

Comment: @user3386109 There is no anonymous enum here, how is that a duplicate?

Comment: @user3386109 `T_GPIO_PIN` is anonymous  enum?

Comment: @user3386109 `enum e_gpio_pin` is anonymous enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the enumeration constant `GPIO_PIN_9` belongs to `T_GPIO_PIN ioPin` they both have the same "essentially enum" type. This is explained in MISRA-C:2012 appendix D.5 and D.6. In MISRA terms, your enum is a *named enum*(*) of type `enum<i>` and its enumeration constants are of the same type.

You would only get problems if you tried to assign an enum some values that are enumeration constants of another enum type. I suppose the tool might get confused because you both used an enum tag and a typedef, perhaps it thinks that `enum e_gpio_pin` and `T_GPIO_PIN ioPin` are distinct enum types.

There is nothing wrong with your code as far as MISRA is concerned. Resolve the warning by posting a bug report to your tool vendor. A work-around for the tool bug might be to remove the enum tag.

---

(*) See appendix D.5

> A named enum type is an enumeration which has a *tag* or which is used
>   in the definition of any object, function or type;

Comment: I would say the opposite: the workaround for the tool bug would be to remove the typedef, and use the tag.

Comment: @user3386109 Either tag or typedef should make it a named enum. I added a quote from appendix D above.